Framer Overrides - Changing text color based on time of the day
i'm currently exploring a way to override a text color using overrides (.tsx) in Framer.
I managed to change dynamically the displayed message but the color seems unable to work and i always get the default text color instead. It looks like the override code cannot edit the default text color. Can anyone help me?
This is the code i'm using and just the text part is working
import { Override } from "framer"
import React from "react"

// Function to determine color and text based on time
const getTimeBasedProps = () => {
    const hours = new Date().getHours()
    let color: string
    let text: string

    if (hours < 18) {
        color = "green" // Morning
        text = "Good morning!"
    } else if (hours >= 18 && hours <= 22) {
        color = "#orange" // Afternoon
        text = "Good afternoon!"
    } else {
        color = "red" // Night
        text = "Good night!"
    }

    return { color, text }
}

// Override function
export function TimeBasedOverride(): Override {
    const { color, text } = getTimeBasedProps()

    return {
        // Ensure you are targeting the correct properties of the component
        text: text,
        style: {
            color: color, // Apply color here
            // Ensure other style properties are correctly set if needed
        },
    }
}


